# Shared transition effect from grid RecyclerView to details activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I'm trying my first shared transition between a `RecyclerView` with a grid layout to a details activity.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_cryptocurrencies"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

For starters, the `transitionName` is set to "cryptocurrency_name" in both the details layout and the `RecyclerView`'s layout.

```
<!-- RecyclerView's item layout -->
<TextView
    style="@style/CurrencyTextView"
    android:id="@+id/tv_cryptocurrency_name"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:maxLength="12"
    android:transitionName="cryptocurrency_name"
    tools:text="Bitcoin" />

...
<!-- Details -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_cryptocurrency_detail_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bitcoin"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:transitionName="cryptocurrency_name"
    .../>
```

`MainActivity`'s overridden method from the adapter:

```
private var tvCryptocurrencyName: TextView? = null
tvCryptocurrencyName = rv_cryptocurrencies.findViewById(R.id.tv_cryptocurrency_name)

override fun onItemClick(cryptocurrency: Cryptocurrency) {
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, tvCryptocurrencyName, "cryptocurrency_name")
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING_CRYPTOCURRENCY_DETAILS, cryptocurrency)
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
}
```

The method to trigger when pressing on an item is set as an interface in the adapter:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(cryptocurrency: Cryptocurrency)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val cryptocurrency = cryptocurrenciesList[position]
    holder.populateUi(cryptocurrency)
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { onItemClickListener?.onItemClick(cryptocurrenciesList[position]) }
}
```

When I press to see the results, the app crashes with the message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gabriel.cryptocurrencies, PID: 4416
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Shared element must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityOptions.java:694)
        at android.app.ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(ActivityOptions.java:649)
        at com.example.gabriel.cryptocurrencies.ui.main.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.kt:50)
        at com.example.gabriel.cryptocurrencies.ui.main.MainAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(MainAdapter.kt:36)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23752)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

and by other tutorials, that's all I need to do. Perhaps the way I try to access the field from the `RecyclerView`'s layout is wrong?

**Edit**

The updated, but yet failing code. Now, it seems that the animation will freeze, because when I press the back button once it will not leave the app, only if I press twice. Also, when editing the code and deploying the changes, the app will load the details view after trying to switch to the details view.

`MainActivity`:

```
override fun onItemClick(cryptocurrency: Cryptocurrency, field: View) {
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CRYPTOCURRENCY_DETAILS, cryptocurrency)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TRANSITION_NAME, cryptocurrency.id)

    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, field, cryptocurrency.id)
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
}
```

`MainAdapter`:

```
val tvCryptocurrencyName = holder.itemView.tv_cryptocurrency_name

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(cryptocurrency: Cryptocurrency, field: View)
}

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { onItemClickListener?.onItemClick(cryptocurrenciesList[position], tvCryptocurrencyName) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set unique transition name for every item in your `RecyclerView`'s adapter in `onBindViewHolder` method.

Something like this:

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.ivIcon, cryptocurrency.id.toString())
```

Send `transitionName` through `Intent`, get this `transitionName` in your details activity and then set it to your `View`:

```
val iconTransitionName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TRANSITION_NAME)
ivIcon.transitionName = iconTransitionName
```

**UPD:**

In `Adapter`'s `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.itemView, cryptocurrenciesList[position].id)
```

In `onItemClick()`:

```
override fun onItemClick(cryptocurrency: Cryptocurrency, textView: TextView) {
    val transitionName = ViewCompat.getTransitionName(textView)
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, textView, transitionName) // You should send exactly this instace of TextView, not by it's id
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING_CRYPTOCURRENCY_DETAILS, cryptocurrency)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING_TRANSITION_NAME, cryptocurrency.id.toString())
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
}
```

In `DetailActivity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
val transitionName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_STRING_TRANSITION_NAME)
tv_cryptocurrency_detail_name.transitionName = transitionName
```

In `values-v21/styles.xml` add:

```
<style name="MaterialAnimations" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

And add this to your `TextView`s:

```
style="@style/MaterialAnimations"
```

Look there for simple example: [Github Repo](https://github.com/khojiakbar17/RecyclerView-Transition-Animation-Example)